# Rolling back last migration not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So, I accidentally created a wrong migration and then I tried to delete it with the `rollback` command like this :

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

It ran successfully and I got this message on the command line:

> Rolling back: 2017_12_07_201338_add_authors_id_to_uploads_id Rolled
>   back:  2017_12_07_201338_add_authors_id_to_uploads_id

But then, after I opened my database on phpmyadmin I discovered that the wrong columns are still there.

Since obviously, the rollback worked I am wondering what am I missing?

P.S. I dont have anything in the down function, since I figuren i don't need that.

Here is what I have in up():

public function up()

```
  {
        //
        Schema::table('authors', function($table){
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        });

        Schema::table('authors', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Comment: if you have "nothing" in `down` then the rollback did "nothing" ... tada ... that is what `down` is for, undoing what you did in `up`  :)

Comment: okay, honestly I wasn't sure how to write the down function. Can you help with that?

Comment: looks like you can just drop that column ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#dropping-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your down method.

```
Schema::table( 'authors', function( Blueprint $table )
        {
            $table->dropColumn( 'user_id' );
        } );
```